# Find out website hosting location

Tags: php, web, web-hosting

Am a member of IT team. Each group of people in my company have their own webpage. somebody is using google sites. 2 websites were not found from this morning. I need to find out one website hosting location. Website URL is something like https://www.mycompanywebsite/groupweb. I checked all the codes in company website (It's developed using PHP MySql), but these 2 groups names or files not found in the codes. Any guess or comments from anybody??

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, can you rephrase your question?

Comment: Would a ping or traceroute help? What about a whois lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a whois lookup. I usually just go to http://who.is and do a search on the URL. The whois lookup will give you a list of information about that domain. Often looking at the nameservers will help. You might need to search the name servers on google (or other search engine) to find out who owns them.